# Socata Soda Api Java Error: function #LIKE is not defined in SoQL

Tags: java, socrata

I am trying to do a like query on a socrata dataset using the [soda-java api](https://github.com/socrata/soda-java) with this code

```
Soda2Consumer consumer = Soda2Consumer.newConsumer("https://data.cityofboston.gov");
SoqlQuery   departmentOfStateQuery = new SoqlQueryBuilder()
                .addSelectPhrase("entered")
                .addSelectPhrase("vendor_name")
                .addSelectPhrase("account_descr")
                .addSelectPhrase("dept_name")
                .setWhereClause("vendor_name like'IBM%'")
                .build();
consumer.query("gqai-h7bg",departmentOfStateQuery,Nomination.LIST_TYPE);
```

But i am getting an error
`Exception in thread "main" com.socrata.exceptions.MalformedQueryError: Error: function #LIKE is not defined in SoQL.: Error: function #LIKE is not defined in SoQL.`
Using a browser is working fine with this

[https://data.cityofboston.gov/resource/gd7m-xsim.json?$where=vendor_name like 'IBM%'](https://data.cityofboston.gov/resource/gd7m-xsim.json?$where=vendor_name%20like%20'IBM%25') even though FF is translating it to `https://data.cityofboston.gov/resource/gd7m-xsim.json?$where=vendor_name%20like%20%27IBM%%27` which encoding I did use with the same result.

Answer (score 0):

`LIKE` is only supported on Version 2.1 API endpoints: https://dev.socrata.com/docs/functions/like.html

Fortunately, a 2.1 endpoint exists for that dataset: https://dev.socrata.com/foundry/data.cityofboston.gov/gd7m-xsim

I was able to get your `LIKE` query working with the following code:

```
    Soda2Consumer consumer = Soda2Consumer.newConsumer("https://data.cityofboston.gov");
    SoqlQuery query = new SoqlQueryBuilder()
            .addSelectPhrase("entered")
            .addSelectPhrase("vendor_name")
            .addSelectPhrase("account_descr")
            .addSelectPhrase("dept_name")
            .setWhereClause("vendor_name LIKE 'IBM%'")
            .build();

    System.out.println(query.toString());
    ClientResponse response = consumer.query("gd7m-xsim", HttpLowLevel.JSON_TYPE, query);
    String payload = response.getEntity(String.class);
    System.out.println(payload);
```

Comment: thanks for that. I saw that like is available for 2.1 and above, but didnt know the dataset wasnt a 2.1. how can i tell if a dataset is v2.1 or not? I am specially intrested for datasets that got from the dataset catalog

Comment: The best way to tell is by clicking the "API Docs" link from either the data catalog or from the "Export" -> "SODA API" sidebar in the dataset itself. It'll automatically make sure you're looking at the docs for the latest version.